# FH_HELO_ALMOST_IP: How to fix HELO for sent e-mails (CentOS 7)

Tags: email, localhost

I've got bad rating of my sent e-mails because of my invalid Helo.
I have no idea how to fix it.

CentOS 7

On Kimsufi

Any ideas?

---

Ok, I've done something and it helps. 
I've made change here **/etc/hostname** with my new hostname: **development.mydomain.com** and added next A records with this domain pointing to my serv. IP . 
I've changed server hostname in Plesk settings as well and after this last step my e-mail got correct 'Helo'.

But I didn't change anything in my Kimsufi panel and he still showing my old hostname... .
Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because your host has a name that somewhat resembles an IP address, for instance `62-210-247-11.rev.poneytelecom.eu`

To fix the problem, you need to do two things:

1. Give your host a proper hostname, which is a fully qualified domain name. For instance, `mail.example.com`. Note that it must not be a "naked domain". On CentOS 7, edit `/etc/hostname` and then reboot.
2. Add a forward DNS record (A record) for your chosen hostname to your DNS records. You do this with whoever is handling the DNS for your domain.
3. Change your reverse DNS to match that hostname; you can do this in Kimsufi's management interface.

Comment: Hi, 1. Done - 2. Got already set A record for IP address - Is that wrong? Or I need to add second A record pointing to new hostname?

Comment: You need to do number 3 now.

Comment: Ok, I've done something and it helps. I've made change here /etc/hostname with my new hostname: development.mydomain.com and added next A records with this domain pointing to my serv. IP . I've changed server hostname in Plesk settings as well and after this last step my e-mail got correct 'Helo'.

But I didn't change anything in my Kimsufi panel and he still showing my old hostname... .

Comment: Number 3 done as well - all fixed. Thank you so much!. You are very helpful :)